# emacs lisp call function with prefix argument programmatically

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to call a function from some elisp code as if I had called it interactively with a prefix argument. Specifically, I want to call grep with a prefix.

The closest I've gotten to making it work is using [`execute-extended-command`](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Call.html), but that still requires that I type in the command I want to call with a prefix...

```
;; calls command with a prefix, but I have to type the command to be called...
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c m g")
                (lambda () (interactive)
                  (execute-extended-command t)))
```

The documentation says that `execute-extended-command` uses `command-execute` to execute the command read from the minibuffer, but I haven't been able to make it work:

```
;; doesn't call with prefix...
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c m g")
                (lambda () (interactive)
                  (command-execute 'grep t [t] t)))
```

Is there any way to call a function **with a prefix yet non-interactively**?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If I'm understanding you right, you're trying to make a keybinding that will act like you typed `C-u M-x grep <ENTER>`.  Try this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c m g")
                (lambda () (interactive)
                  (setq current-prefix-arg '(4)) ; C-u
                  (call-interactively 'grep)))
```

Although I would probably make a named function for this:

```
(defun grep-with-prefix-arg ()
  (interactive)
  (setq current-prefix-arg '(4)) ; C-u
  (call-interactively 'grep))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c m g") 'grep-with-prefix-arg)
```

Comment: It doesn't matter in this particular case, but in general, I'd use `(let ((current-prefix-arg '(4))) (call-interactively 'grep))` so that the behavior of subsequent functions called in the commands is not affected.

Comment: @cjm why 4? C-u is 4?

Answer (score 17):

Or you could just use a [keyboard macro](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html#Keyboard-Macros)

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-l") (kbd "C-u C-SPC"))
```

In this example, the key combination "s-l" (s ("super") is the "windows logo" key on a PC keyboard) will go up the mark ring, just like you if typed "C-u C-SPC".