# How to define a function to run multiple shells on Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

As I known, "C-u M-x shell" can be used to run multiple shells. 
But how to define a function to do the same thing as "C-u M-x shell" do ?

Comment: You can also look at [multi-term](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2010/06/console-apps-in-emacs-with-multi-term.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defun my-named-shell ()
  "Equivalent to C-u M-x shell RET"
  (interactive)
  (shell (get-buffer
          (read-buffer
           "Shell buffer: "
           (generate-new-buffer-name "*shell*")))))
```

I used `describe-function` and `find-function` to examine the behaviour of `shell`, and its `interactive` declaration in particular, and then I just copied the necessary code to turn that into an argument for a non-interactive call to the `shell` function (but wrapping it in `get-buffer` so as to provide a buffer argument).

I've actually left out some code which dealt with remote files, because the comments in that code seemed a bit confused. If you weren't in the habit of using `C-u M-x shell` in buffers accessing remote files via Tramp, that omission won't affect you.

That all said, an even simpler (and more complete) approach is simply:

```
(defun my-named-shell ()
  "Equivalent to C-u M-x shell RET"
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-prefix-arg '(4)))
    (call-interactively 'shell)))
```

For more information, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9388058/324105

In this instance `current-prefix-arg` could be any non-nil value, but I think it's a good habit to use a value that `C-u` actually generates.